# check or uncheck radio buttons when i click on text

Tags: html, radio-button

```
<input type="radio" name="allotdeallot" value="Allotment" />Allotment
<input type="radio" name="allotdeallot" value="De-Allotment" />De-Allotment
```

I have two radio buttons which I want to check or uncheck on label click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per HTML standards, every form element must have `label` attach to it. You wish to hide the text of label, you can hide the text of the `lable`, by using `position:absolute` to the `label`. So here is your answer,

```
<input id="allotment" type="radio" name="allotdeallot" value="Allotment" /><label for="allotment">Allotment</label>
<input id="de-allotment" type="radio" name="allotdeallot" value="De-Allotment" /><label for="de-allotment">De-Allotment</label>
```

The `id of the input field` must be same with `for attribute of the label`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<label>` tag and add the `id` attribute to the `radio` button:

```
<input type="radio" name="allotdeallot" id="allotment" value="Allotment" /><label for="allotment">Allotment</label>
<input type="radio" name="allotdeallot" id="deallotment" value="De-Allotment" /><label for="deallotment">De-Allotment</label>
```

[More information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)